# Extracting a Rails application into a plugin or engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a Rails 2.3 application which I would like to extract into a plugin, or engine. The application has user authentication, and basic cms capabilities supported by ancestry plugin.

I want to extract the logic for the application into a plugin/engine so that I can use this code for future projects, with a different "skin" or "theme" if required.

I'm not entirely sure I actually understand the difference between plugin and engine concepts, so that would be a good first point.

What is the best approach, are there any good starting points, links, explanations, examples that I should follow. Also, with the release of R3 to consider, is there anything that I should be aware of for that, with regards to plugins etc.

I am going to start off by watching Ryan's http://railscasts.com/episodes/149-rails-engines
but obviously thats over a year old now, so one of the challenges I'm faced with is finding the most up to date and relevant information on this subject.

All tips and help gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, converting an application is pretty straigtforward. Just create a plugin-folder, put an app-folder inside containing all yor model-views-controllers folders, and that's it.

You will have to manage your migrations yourself though. Also you have to define rake-tasks to copy files to your public folder. I think the railscasts is still pretty up-to-date, if anything it is now easier in rails 2.3.

Good luck!

[EDIT: for rails3] Rails 3 engines are very clean and powerful. Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/af7e572c2dc973add221) by Jose Valim.

Comment: Would a Rails 2 engine work in a Rails 3 app? Is this still the same process or has it changed since this question was posted?

Comment: A rails 2 engine still works in rails 3. But rails 3 engines have a much nicer integration, much more is possible now. So you can still use rails 2 engines, but it really pays to convert them to rails 3 engines. A rails 2 engine is a plugin, a rails 3 plugin will most likely be a gem: much cleaner :)

Comment: @Passionate: mmmmmm weird internet where links disappear after two years (sarcasm intended). I googled for a similar link and updated my answer.

Comment: how to include that plugin/engine into another rails application?

Comment: This is a very old answer (from 2010). At the moment though it is still very easy to build plugins, and include them in your rails application. A rails plugin is a piece of shared code from the `app` folder, can have its own migrations and assets (although since rails 6 and webpacker this is more difficult). A plugin is now a gem, and you can include like you do with any gem (which does not mean you have to publish them to rubygems, one can load a gem from a folder or github), See for more info: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Answer (score 3):

You will probably be better off focusing your engine on Rails 3, as opposed to trying to make it compatible for Rails 2 and Rails 3, due to the backwards incompatible changes.   Here is a more up to date [tutorial for Rails 3](http://www.stubbleblog.com/index.php/2011/04/writing-rails-engines-getting-started/)

also the book "[Crafting Rails applications](http://plataformatec.com.br/crafting-rails-applications/)"  by Rails Core member Jose Valim, has a good chapter on it.   Int he shows how to use his tool [EngineX](https://github.com/josevalim/enginex) which generates a Rails 3 engine structure, so you can more easily create engines for your Rails 3 projects.  His  gem [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is also a rails engine which is also nice, because you can easily customize it by copying the templates into the application directory, and allowing you to subclass the controllers that you want to customize more.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a plugin is an entirely different process than writing an app, if you already have your app code it should be straightforward converting it into a plugin.

Consider that if you use third-party plugins in your app it could get pretty messy.